# Skipping an new/transient NHibernate entity's ID generator strategy when an ID is already provided

Tags: nhibernate, null, generator

Just a quickie ... I have the following ID generator strategy for one of my mapped classes:

```
<id name="UID" type="System.Guid">
    <column name ="UID" sql-type ="uniqueidentifier" />
    <generator class="guid.comb" />
</id>
```

The entity in question is involved in synchronisation / merging behaviours from which it is necessary to have a globally unique identifier.

When an entity is created on a client application for the first time, it's `UID` property gets assigned so that it is the same value of the equivilent entity on the server.

However the above ID generator strategy overwrites any value provided for new/transient entities.

Whats the fix? Will I have to remove the generator strategy and assign my own GUIDs? Or is the generator strategy configurable to only generate a `guid.comb` when required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this by making UID a private field and controlling access through the property.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Guid _uid;

    protected MyClass() { // parameterless ctor for NH }

    public MyClass(Guid uid) { _uid = uid; // assign on creation }

    public Guid Uid
    {
        get { return _uid; }
        private set { // do nothing or compare _uid to Guid.Empty and set }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately NHibernate appears to be updating it's internal entity state with a generated UID, resulting in the following exception:

identifier of an instance of csl.Risk.Structure.RiskClass was altered from 12ae645e-c50f-4fc5-b0ff-9db900bd9a4e to 42e565c7-8dd3-416f-89a2-9db801086d93; where the 1st guid is a generated one and the second is the assigned one. Bummer :(

Comment: New answer: You will have to remove the generator strategy and assign your own GUIDs. :-)

Comment: I am going down this road, `NHibernate.Id.GuidCombGenerator.Generate(null, null);` does produce a comb guid btw so am happy ... Let's hope it doesn't confuse the transient detection behaviour! I'll score you once I've verified it.